# Regex to validate continuous characters in a String

Tags: javascript, regex

Sorry if this is a easy question. Is there a regex to validate if four continuous characters in a String are numbers(for a year for example)?

For example  glorer1891kl -> true, 
74djada -> false

i need to validate if in the string exist four continuous characters, each character is a number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[0-9]{4}

will do it.  There's a great website for testing this....

http://gskinner.com/RegExr/